# traceback nameerror in python2

Tags: python-2.7, nameerror, traceback

I am relatively new to programming,
and i was trying to do a checkbutton and i'm getting a traceback (most recent call last): and NameError message. please help. thanks!

```
chack_button = Chackbutton(root, text="show password", commend=show_password)
chack_button.place(x=290, y=170)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new2.py", line 19, in <module>
    chack_button = Chackbutton(root, text="show password", commend=show_password)
NameError: name 'Chackbutton' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written `Chackbutton` instead of `Checkbutton`